# Error Import Parquet in Windows

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, parquet

I'm trying to install Parquet file format to use it with Apache Spark. I learned that I had to install Thrift, ThriftPy, and Python-Snappy in order to fully install Parquet.

I install Thrift using the command

```
pip install thrift
```

Then I installed python-snappy manually through a wheel file found [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-snappy). This was because I was unable to install python-snappy automatically. Anyways, python-snappy was successfully installed.

I also installed ThrifPy using the similar command

```
pip install ThriftPy
```

And finally, I used pip to install parquet which was successful. After installing, when I try to import parquet, it raises the error as

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ThriftParserError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-942008defa53> in <module>()
----> 1 import parquet

C:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\parquet\__init__.py in <module>()
 17 from thriftpy.protocol.compact import TCompactProtocolFactory
 18 
---> 19 from . import encoding
 20 from . import schema
 21 from .converted_types import convert_column

C:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\parquet\encoding.py in <module>()
 17 
 18 THRIFT_FILE = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "parquet.thrift")
---> 19 parquet_thrift = thriftpy.load(THRIFT_FILE, 
module_name=str("parquet_thrift"))  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
 20 
 21 logger = logging.getLogger("parquet")  # pylint: disable=invalid-name

 C:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\thriftpy\parser\__init__.pyc in load(path, 
 module_name, include_dirs, include_dir)
 28     real_module = bool(module_name)
 29     thrift = parse(path, module_name, include_dirs=include_dirs,
 ---> 30                    include_dir=include_dir)
 31 
 32     if real_module:

 C:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\thriftpy\parser\parser.pyc in parse(path, 
 module_name, include_dirs, include_dir, lexer, parser, enable_cache)
 494         raise ThriftParserError('ThriftPy does not support generating 
 module '
 495                                 'with path in protocol \'{}\''.format(
 --> 496                                     url_scheme))
 497 
 498     if module_name is not None and not module_name.endswith('_thrift'):

 ThriftParserError: ThriftPy does not support generating module with path in 
 protocol 'c'
```

Would someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

For reference, I'm using anaconda Python 2.7 on a Jupyter notebook. My OS is Windows 7 , and I'm using Spark on a single cluster.

Comment: The Python `parquet` package is outdated, try to use `pyarrow` for reading Apache Parquet files: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html

Comment: Thanks a lot...But pyarrow is only available for Python 3.5 or higher..At this moment, my boss will not allow me to convert to Python 3.5, so i can't use it...Is there a solution for Python 2.7 ? thanks again

Comment: Due to the nature of the available Python builds on Windows, it is sadly only possible to build with 3.5+ on Windows. If you want to use `pyarrow` with older Pythons, you need to use Linux or OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the parser code in the windows side. It is in site-packages of python.

For Example:- C:\Anaconda\python27\Lib\site-packages\thriftpy\parser\parser.py

Modify the 488 line:

```
 #if url_scheme == '':

 if len(url_scheme) <= 1:
```

Then try again.